# apt-get commands out of sync

Tags: apt

I'm running Ubuntu server 15.10, and all of a sudden `apt-get` got confused about which packages are required and which aren't. I think I ran `apt-get -f install` before this started happening, because there were unmet dependencies.

When I run dist-upgrade, it tells me there's plenty of stuff that could be removed:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  aspell aspell-en dictionaries-common emacsen-common enchant hunspell-en-us
  libaspell15 libenchant1c2a libhunspell-1.3-0 libhunspell-1.3-0v5 libqdbm14
  libxslt1.1 php-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  php-pear
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

So I ran autoremove, but then this happened:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  php-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 62,5 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 106550 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing php-common (18+deb.sury.org~wily+1) ...
root root 1733 /var/lib/php/sessions
```

Not really knowing what to do I tried to do update && dist-upgrade again, which installed `php-common` back, and kept on saying I should run autoremove.

I have no idea what to do.

**More info**

Output for `apt-cache policy php-pear`

```
php-pear:
  Installed: 5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1
  Candidate: 1:1.10.1+submodules+notgz-3+deb.sury.org~wily+2
  Version table:
     1:1.10.1+submodules+notgz-3+deb.sury.org~wily+2 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-7.0/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

Output for `apt-cache policy php-common`

```
php-common:
  Installed: 18+deb.sury.org~wily+1
  Candidate: 18+deb.sury.org~wily+1
  Version table:
 *** 18+deb.sury.org~wily+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-7.0/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: No package on your system depends on `php-common`. There is no problem.

Comment: Add the output of `sudo apt-get install php-pear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `php-common` isn't in the standard Wily repositories. But you have added the PPA `ppa:ondrej/php-7.0` and the package `php-pear` in this PPA depends on `php-common`, which is also in this PPA.

Your problem is, `php-pear` isn't installable, for whatever reason, but `php-common`. So the package `php-common` will be installed only to discover later that it is unnecessary, because the "parent" package `php-pear` could not be installed.

Comment: It seems you are right. I think the underlying problem is that there's colliding packages from the standard Wily repo and from Ondřej Surý's PHP7 repo.

Comment: Using `ppa-purge` to remove the PHP7 repo and then doing update & upgrade seems to have resolved the problem. Thanks!